# format of gcc -print-search-dirs output

Tags: gcc

when run from the command line (win7 cmd) gcc -print-search-dirs produces:

```
install: C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/
programs: =C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/;C:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
libraries: =C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../lib/;C:/mingw510/x86_64-510-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/mingw/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/;C:/mingw510/x86_64-510-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/mingw/lib/../lib/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../;C:/mingw510/x86_64-510-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/mingw/lib/`
```

I understand the semi-colons (like PATH) but I'm not clear on the `/../` as shown. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same meaning as `..` in any path specification, i.e. the parent directory. 
For example, `C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/` corresponds to `C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/`.

Comment: Insert "Ah ha moment " here…I let the lack if idiomatic understanding block what should have been obvious! Thank you.